# Code generation via T4 template in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: methods, entity-framework-4.1, t4

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 in web application(database first method) and I intend to use t4 templates to generating code. I'm not sure about that if I can have some methods for implement all the entities database operations. e.g I want to have an insert method in my template and using this method for all of my entities. Is it possible?